# Problems with multiple monitors

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display, 17.10

since updating to 17.10 I have a problem with my multiple monitor configuration. I have a Thinkpad X1 with two extra monitors connected with the OneLink+ external dock.

When I log back in from locked screen, the system does not turn on one of the external monitors. The configuration in Settings -> Displays is correct, but I have to remove one monitor, save config and then revert to make the extra monitor turn on.

I've tried with Wayland and with Xorg, and the problem persists. I've looked around in the forums and I haven't found anything that helps.

Any suggestions?